# Обновление информации в базе при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

Нужно при нажатии на ссылку, например на:

```
<div class="col m3 like"><a name="Like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up " aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
```

чтобы в базу шла информация из соседнего дива:

```
<div class="border "><p class="likeNum">{{$post->likes}}</p></div>             </div>
```

без обновления страницы. Знаю, что надо сделать через ajax, но, кажется, я слишком давно не спал, чтобы до меня дошло как что сделать, может подскажите?

```
<div class="col m4 s12">
<div class="car ">
<div class="foto">
  <div class="infoTab center"><a href="{{url('/postinfo/')}}/{{$post->id}}"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-5x"></i></a></div>
  <img src="{{ $post->images[0]->img_path }}" alt="Car Photos">
</div>
<div class="postInfo">
  <div class="nickName left"><p>{{$post->user->username}}</p></div>
  <div class="date right"><p>{{$post->date}}</p></div>
</div>
<div class="carNumber">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="img/Azerbaijan.png">
    <p>AZ</p>
  </div>
  <p>{{$post->numbers[0]->nmb_title}}</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col m12 ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m8 DL">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col m5">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col m3 like">

                <a name="Like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col m6">
                <div class="border "><p class="likeNum">{{$post->likes}}</p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col m5 ">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col m3 disLike"><a name="DisLike"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down " aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
              <div class="col m6">
                <div class="border"><p class="dislikeNum">{{$post->dislikes}}</p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col m4 right share">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://localhost:8000/postinfo/{{$post->id}}/FBshareArticle"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать, что именно у вас не получилось?
Может, стоит выспаться и попробовать решить задачу самостоятельно, а не просить поработать других?

Comment: к сожалению слтшком поджимает время =) если была бы возможность не стал бы людей напрягать

Comment: В таком случае, вам на любую фриланс-биржу. Там вы и задачу решите и никого не напряжёте.

Comment: спасибо за идею

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас подключен jQuery то можно примерно так:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("a[name=Like]").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
      data: {
        'my_var': $("p.likeNum").text()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Request Successful")
      },
      error: function(xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Ну и потом в контроллере обработать данную переменную:

```
if (Request::ajax()) {
    $myVar= Request::only('my_var');
    // Делаем то что нужно с переменной
}
```